# Drag and drop jquery (iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, drag-and-drop

Iam having the exact problem as the question below. Please anyone give a hint how to solve the problem.

I try to make a textarea that is writable (and where user can customize text (bold etc) and that can be drag and dropped.

the textarea_iframe* is writable but only before being drag and dropped. After being drag and dropped it is not writable anymore... the classic textarea (not an iframe and here just as an exemple) is still writable.

(*my textarea has to allow users to customise the texte (bold, change color) this is why I use an iframe...)

Here a link to the code I have done: http://js.do/Aleqxs/solving_textarea_coloriable_with_drag_and_drop

Does any one know if it is possible to drag and drop that textarea and still get the text inside...

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` is a separate document with it's own Document Object Model. I do not believe you can store an entire page/document within a jQuery UI object when you are dragging.

You will need to store the iframe contents and then retrieve it after the drop.